# Is a low specific heat capacity for the material of the calorimeter good or bad?

Tags: thermodynamics, calorimetry

I wish to ask if a low specific heat capacity of the material of the calorimeter means that the calorimeter would be more exact as it takes less heat for the material to reach equilibrium. I thought it would make more sense if it was the opposite and that you would want a substance with a higher specific heat capacity.

Comment: I would assume that if your absolute error in a measurement is fixed across all samples, higher heat capacities are better, since then the relative error in a measurement is lower.